# all li's are clicked after click on one li - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `li`'s and `ul`'s as a hierarchy tree .

but when I click on a `li`, all `li`'s clicked .

for example when I click on `id="11"`, my console log got me this message:

```
11
10
9
1
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("li.change_select").click(function() {
    var category_id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(category_id);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
        <li id="1" class="change_select">بدون دسته بندی
            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                <li id="2" class="change_select">تست
                    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                        <li id="3" class="change_select">تست 2</li>
                        <li id="4" class="change_select">عنوان</li>
                        <li id="5" class="change_select">تست
                            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                <li id="6" class="change_select">تست
                                    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                        <li id="7" class="change_select">تست 4
                                            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                                <li id="8" class="change_select">تست 5</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="9" class="change_select">شماره 2
                    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                        <li id="10" class="change_select">شماره 3
                            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                <li id="11" class="change_select">شماره 6</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

> [e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/): in order to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

My snippet:

```js
$("li.change_select").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var category_id = $(this).attr('id');

  console.log(category_id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
        <li id="1" class="change_select">بدون دسته بندی
            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                <li id="2" class="change_select">تست
                    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                        <li id="3" class="change_select">تست 2</li>
                        <li id="4" class="change_select">عنوان</li>
                        <li id="5" class="change_select">تست
                            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                <li id="6" class="change_select">تست
                                    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                        <li id="7" class="change_select">تست 4
                                            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                                <li id="8" class="change_select">تست 5</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="9" class="change_select">شماره 2
                    <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                        <li id="10" class="change_select">شماره 3
                            <ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
                                <li id="11" class="change_select">شماره 6</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening for bubbling up the DOM tree. You should use [**`stopPropagation()`**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) like following.

```
$("li.change_select").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    var category_id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(category_id);
});
```